# Pandas Pivot output to html

Tags: pandas, formatting, pivot

Does anyone know how to fix the issue "no attr='labels' under dataframe.index" when dateframe is generated from Pivot?
Please find below two examples,
first one (pivot dataframe) return error 'index has no attr 'labels',
the second one ('groupby' dataframe) works.

*Example for 'Pivot':*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'A' : ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
            'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B1'],
            'QTY': [1., 2., 3., 4.],}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='QTY')

print "-------Result---------"
print df_pivot
print "------View Index------"
print df_pivot.index
print "------View Label------"
print df_pivot.index.labels
```

*Output:*

```
-------Result---------
B    B1   B2
A
A1  1.0  2.0
A2  4.0  3.0
------View Index------

    Index([u'A1', u'A2'], dtype='object', name=u'A')

------View Label------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test6.py", line 15, in 
    print df_pivot.index.labels
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

*Example for 'Groupby':*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'A' : ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
            'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B1'],
            'QTY': [1., 2., 3., 4.],}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
#df_pivot = df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='QTY')
df_gb = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'QTY':'sum'})
print "-------Result---------"
print df_gb
print "------View Index------"
print df_gb.index
print "------View Label------"
print df_gb.index.labels
```

*Output:*

```
-------Result---------
       QTY
A  B
A1 B1  1.0
   B2  2.0
A2 B1  4.0
   B2  3.0
------View Index------

    MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A1', u'A2'], [u'B1', u'B2']],
               labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
               names=[u'A', u'B'])

------View Label------
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example and show the full error message, including the line that triggers the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Index hasn't labels attr, so I have to add "isinstance( index, pd.Index)" to apply different logic.